# Can not edit file symlinked (Permission denied)

Tags: dot-files

I started using **dotfiles** to sync everything I need to **github**. But I got some problem when symblink config files from `dotfiles/` to `~/`

**Examples:**

```
$ rm ~/.config/termite/config
$ ln -s ~/dotfiles/termite/config - > ~/.config/termite/config
```

`$ ll ~/dotfiles/termite

total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 hieuc users 1.9K Nov 18 15:19 config`

It won't let me edit, and it cannot be read by ***termite***

```
~/.config/termite/config [Permission Denied]
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to execute `~/dotfiles/termite/config` using the symlink?

Comment: Yep, because I want to organize all of the config file in dotfiles/ and keep it update easier.

Comment: Is the file itself executable? All the output of `ll ~/dotfiles/termite/config` to your question.

Comment: Note: the command `ln -s ~/dotfiles/termite/config - > ~/.config/termite/config` does something different than what you expected.

Comment: I didn't notice earlier but in addition to what Ipor said, if you just want a symlink, the correct command is `ln -s ~/dotfiles/termite/config ~/.config/termite/config`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I don't know it can executable or not. I updated ```ll``` to my question
@IporSircer My bad, I just put  ```- >``` there to explain.
My correct symblink is ```ln -s ~/dotfiles/termite/config ~/.config/termite/config```

Comment: Also when I test with file ```~/dotfiles/README.md``` and symblink it into ```~/README.md``` it is got same problem, it's unreadable.
https://pastebin.com/ZuVB6qpd

Answer (score 0):

The file is readable by everyone as is denoted by the `r` bit for user, group, and others.

Your file is not executable as is denoted by the lack of `x` for everyone. That is what is giving you the `[Permission Denied]` error.

Make the file executable with this:

```
chmod +x ~/.config/termite/config
```

That will add execute permissions and the output off `ll ~/.config/termite/config` will look like this:

```
-rw-r-xr-x 1 hieuc users 1.9K Nov 18 15:19 config
```

You will then be able to execute the file with no issues either with this command:

```
~/.config/termite/config
```

Or by cd'ing into the directory that contains the file and then executing it:

```
cd ~/.config/termite/config

./config
```

Comment: Thank for your helping but I think I know what is my problem.
Because when I symblink I am already in ```~/dotfiles/termite/``` and use ```ln -s config ~/.config/termite/config``` and when I try to edit or read it'll come up with error ```Too many levels of symbolic links```.
After that I tried to symblink full path like this ```$pwd (~/dotfiles/termite/) $ ln -s ~/dotfiles/termite/config ~/.config/termite/config``` And it is editable right now.
Again, thank for your time to helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting permission denied. In my case the link was somehow broken I had to delete the linked file and then relink it

```
ln -s /intranet/note/zshtips.html zshtips.html
```

I could/should have tested the validity of the link with

```
readlink zshtips.html
```